# js data url Получить загруженную картинку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.
Загружается картинка в `img src=`

Необходимо получить `data` `url` загруженной картинки без обращения повторно к серверу, т.е. загруженную из кеша.

Как это сделать используя js/jquery?

Задача отравить для обработки загруженную картинку.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow. Попробуйте объяснить более подробно, чего Вы хотите. Например, что означает "data url ... картинки"? Или "отправить для обработки загруженную картинку" - отправить куда?

Answer (score 0):

Url картинки на jquery:

```
$(img).attr('src');
```

Класс можете навесить:

html:

```
<img class='my_img' src=''>
```

js:

```
$('.my_img').attr('src');
```

Если про это вопрос.